# Issue with creating shaped div at 100% width

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am trying to create diagonal div, at the bottom of another div. It should look like this: http://storage8.static.itmages.com/i/17/0706/h_1499339517_4995911_421bf6ae42.png.

I have problem when I adding 100vw value to my border-left, because horizontal scrollbar appears on my website. I also tried use Jquery to find the width of the body. It works but when I resize my browser, border width does not change. Any suggestions how to fix it?

```js
     var actualInnerWidth = $(".background-gradient").prop("clientWidth"); 
$('.background-gradient').css({
   'border-top':'50px solid red',
   'border-left': actualInnerWidth + 'px solid transparent'
});
```

```css
    .banner {
   min-height: 50vh;
   margin: 0;
   padding:0;
   background-color: red;
 }
.background-gradient {
   width:100%;
   height:50px;
   background-color:yellow;
 }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="jumbotron banner">
</div>
<div class="background-gradient">
</div>
```

Here is jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/b49mmm9a/1/

Answer (score 1):

Try This i think you find this

```css
.box {
  background-color: skyblue;
  margin-top: 40px;
  padding: 1% 20px;
  /* Added a percentage value for top/bottom 
            padding to keep 
            the wrapper inside of the parent */
  -webkit-transform: skewY(-5deg);
  -moz-transform: skewY(-5deg);
  -ms-transform: skewY(-5deg);
  -o-transform: skewY(-5deg);
  transform: skewY(-5deg);
}

.box>.wrapper {
  -webkit-transform: skewY(5deg);
  -moz-transform: skewY(5deg);
  -ms-transform: skewY(5deg);
  -o-transform: skewY(5deg);
  transform: skewY(5deg);
}
```

```html
<div class="box">
  <div class="wrapper">
    <h1>This is a heading</h1>
    <p>This is a sub-heading</p>
    <p>

      How do I draw a Diagonal div?
      </a>
    </p>
  </div>
</div>
```

http://jsbin.com/daruruhola/edit?html,css,js,output

Answer (score 0):

Here is simple JS/jQuery Code.

```
function setBorder(){
      var actualInnerWidth = $(".background-gradient").prop("clientWidth"); 
      $('.background-gradient').css({
        'border-top':'50px solid red',
        'border-left': actualInnerWidth + 'px solid transparent'
            }); 
        }

$(document).ready(function(){
    setBorder();
});

      $(window).resize( function(){
        setBorder();
      });
```

check codepen here https://codepen.io/sajiddesigner/pen/PjBRxQ

Answer (score 0):

```css
.kontainer {
  width: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

```html
<div class="kontainer">
  <div class="banner"></div>
 <div class="background-gradient"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: While this code snippet may solve the question, [including an explanation](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion.